# How to call a method on an object in an arrayMap?

Tags: android

I want to call a method of a object inside an `arrayMap`, but when I try to write the code it doesn't work.

```
   Object myObject = new Object();
   public ArrayMap arr = new ArrayMap();
   arr.put(0,myObject);
   arr.get(0).myMethod(); //this doesn't work
   //i have to do this:
   Object newObject = arr.get(0);
```

What can I do to be able to use the function on my object whitout having to declare another object?

Edit: corrected `newObject.myFunction();` in `newObject.myMethod();`

Comment: In one you are using `myMethod()` the other you are using `myFunction()` is that a typo?

Comment: Yes i corrected it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify generic type parameters:

```
public ArrayMap<Integer,MyObject> arr = new ArrayMap<>();
```

`// MyObject class has the method myMethod`

then you can write:

```
arr.get(0).myMethod()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
public ArrayMap arr = new ArrayMap<MyObject>();
arr.put(0,myObject);
arr.get(0).myMethod();
```

if you try it like this I assume it should work.

I used the term MyObject instead of Object because it is bad practive to call your class Object as it is a very basic type of class in Java.